# Where Spring Security obtains JSESSIONID from local host server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, weblogic12c

I need to figure out in which class Spring Security obtains the JSESSIONID from the host server (in my case WebLogic 12 cluster). All I need to do is logging it, for debug purposes, every time Spring asks for it (I think when someone's logging in).

Answer (score 0):

Normally [`SecurityContextRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html) is used to persist the user security context. By default HttpSession is used as per javadoc:

> Used by SecurityContextPersistenceFilter to obtain the context which should be used for the current thread of execution and to store the context once it has been removed from thread-local storage and the request has completed.
>
> The persistence mechanism used will depend on the implementation, but most commonly the HttpSession will be used to store the context.

The other classes to look at is [`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.html) which uses the repository (usually [`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html)) to load and store the context as part of the request filter chain.